# Using Spotify Developer with curl

Tags: curl

So I'm trying to understand API, but I'm stuck at getting the token here
https://youtu.be/WXsD0ZgxjRw?t=2953

Authorization seems wrong on my code, but I just can't solve this, this result in this error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Invalid access token"
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The access token shows Spotify you are allowed to access their API, it authenticates you. You did not specify the request you are making to the Spotify API, making it hard to answer this question.

However, you get an invalid access token error. This probably means you did not (successfully) add the access token to your request.

The following is an example cURL request to get an album, XXX should be replaced with your access token for the request to succeed:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4aawyAB9vmqN3uQ7FjRGTy \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar challenge when studying API fundamentals through the same tutorial. Here's what I discovered: The token displayed in the REQUESTED SAMPLE, having '...' with it, is not an actual token. To obtain a real token, you need to follow the instructions on this page: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/getting-started#create-an-app.